# Endorsement Policy based on chaincode-method level

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

## Can I set endorsement policy for chiancode based on chaincode-method level? Below is scenario ::

I have two functions let’s say fun1() and fun2(). Both functions are in same chaincode let’s say "test.go"
I have three peers let’s say A,B and C

- For fun1() I want endorsement from peer A and peer B.
- For fun2() I want endorsement from peer B and peer C.

Query ::

## Can I specify different endorsement policy on function/method level in hyperledger-fabric when all functions/methods are in a single chaincode?

I don't see anything like that in hyperledger-fabric documentation to specify endorsement policy based on function level.

"Specifying endorsement policies for a chaincode" ::

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/endorsement-policies.html#specifying-endorsement-policies-for-a-chaincode

I'm using Fabric v1.1, What could be better approach to handle such situations when different method are present in same chaincode ".go" and each method have requirement to get endorsement from different peers.
Does this mean that  :: “All business logic which requires same endorsement policy should be coded in same chaincode?”.

I heard, there is coming this new feature "State-based Endorsement", unsure if this feature can help me with such requirement.

https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-8812

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't.

Having such a thing would cripple Fabric's security:

Let's assume we have organizations **A, B, C** and a chaincode with 2 functions, **f** and **g** each with its own endorsement policy:

- function **f**'s endorsement policy is **A** and **B**,
- function **g**'s endorsement policy is (**A** and **C**) or (**B** and **C**).
- **f** controls asset transfer, while **g** control asset creation.

Since you execute transactions on only a subset of peers, if **A** and **C** collude, they can dishonestly transfer assets by crafting a transaction that claims to invoke **g**, but one that has an artificial read-write set that actually does something that **g** can't do (transfer an asset, something that only **f** can do) and signing it with a private key that corresponds to an identity from organization **A**, and a private key that corresponds to an identity from organization **C**.
    When the peers would validate this transaction, they'd use **g**'s endorsement policy and the business impact on the system would be that an asset was moved without consent from organization **B**, even though the endorsement policy of **f** should have prevented this from happening.

Clearly, this happens because since Fabric is an execute-order-validate blockchain - the transactions are executed on a subset of the peers, and if the endorsement policy is satisfied by the endorsements of the transaction - you have no real way of knowing whether the transaction was executed honestly or not since the peers are ignorant of how the transaction write set was created based on the read set and the chaincode proposal and thus can't distinguish between a maliciously crafted one from an honest one.

> I heard, there is coming this new feature "State-based Endorsement",
>   unsure if this feature can help me with such requirement.

No, it won't help you. State based endorsement just means that the endorsement policy can be specified explicitly for each key, and then to update the key or to change its endorsement policy you need to satisfy the endorsement policy, and if there is no endorsement policy set, then you need to satisfy the endorsement policy of the chaincode.

For more information, you can take a look a discussion on this very question, including a mention of state based endorsement, in - [FAB-11246](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-11246)

Comment: I have very similar problem. Basically I have a network of three organizations. Two banks and one regulator organization. There are three types of assets. Creation of one of the assets requires that only that creator bank may create the asset and no other bank may create that asset in a way that the asset belongs to other bank. There is an asset that requires for creation an endorsement from a bank and the regulator. Finally third asset is being created when two banks agree thus requiring endorsement from two banks, but the outcome of transaction depends on the state of other types of assets.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your quick response and sorry for delayed response.
Your example of asset creation/transfer clears possible trust issue if we try to attempt endorsement policy based on chaincode-method level.

So, I need to divide my chaincode logic into to seperate chaincode files and deploy it on two separate channels so that I can set different endorsement policy for each of channel.

As I understand from below hyperledger-fabric documentation, I'm trying to achieve something like "dynamic addition of endorsement policies" which I believe not allowed.

"*3.1. Endorsement policy specification*" ::

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/arch-deep-dive.html#endorsement-policy-specification

> "Therefore, dynamic addition of endorsement policies is not allowed,
>   but can be supported in future."

I would love to hear Hyperledger facric community exploring more on such "dynamic addition of endorsement policies" in future release.